# Evaluating a Future Boolean asynchronously using Scala and Play

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a method that returns a Future[Boolean] in a Play controller and i want to evaluate that using async but i can't seem to get it to compile. 
The following will work:

```
  def health = Action {
    logger.info("Endpoint method: health")
    val isHealthy = healthCheckService.checkDynamo()
    val b: Boolean = Await.result(isHealthy, scala.concurrent.duration.Duration(5, "seconds"))
    Ok(Json.toJson(HealthCheckResponse(b.toString)))
  }
```

But i don't think i want that Await in there. So i'm trying things like this with no success:

```
 def health =
    Action.async {
      Future {
        logger.info("Endpoint method: health")


        healthCheckService.checkDynamo() match {
          case Future.successful(true)  => Ok(Json.toJson("false"))
          case false => Ok(Json.toJson("true"))
        }



        val r = healthCheckService.checkDynamo() match {
          case true  => Ok(Json.toJson("false"))
          case false => Ok(Json.toJson("true"))
        }

      }
    }
```

I can't even get those to compile to test them out.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def health = Action.async {
  healthCheckService.checkDynamo().map {
    case true => Ok(Json.toJson("false"))
    case false => Ok(Json.toJson("true"))
  }
}
```

Let Play handle the awaiting for you under the hood. That is, `Action.async` accepts  a `Future`, which `checkDynamo()` already returns. All you have to do is `map` it to the appropriate result.

Answer (score 2):

With `Futures` you have to use combinators like `map` and `flatMap` to express the final value. For example:

```
Action.async {
  healthCheckService.checkDynamo()
    .map { result =>  // boolean
      HealthCheckResponse(result.toString)
    }
    .map(Json.toJson(_))
    .map(Ok(_))
}
```

(You can merge `map`s above to one `map` and construct the final `Ok` value there; it is more or less a matter of taste)

If you have, say, two async calls which you want to execute and return a result based on their results, you can use `flatMap`, which could be easily expressed using a `for` comprehension:

```
Action.async {
  for {
    result1 <- someService.someCall()
    result2 <- anotherService.anotherCall(result1.someProperty)
    finalResult = SomeFinalResultType(result1, result2)
  } yield Ok(Json.toJson(finalResult))
}
```

If you are not familiar with futures, you might want to read some tutorial which explains their nature, how to combine them and how to get useful results from them, like this one: http://hello-scala.com/920-scala-futures.html